# Symmetry of function defined by integral

Tags: integration, symmetric-functions, symmetry

([Originally posed in Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268789/symmetry-of-function-defined-by-integral) in Jan 2013.  Received no complete answers as of yet.)

Define a function $f(\alpha, \beta)$, $\alpha \in (-1,1)$, $\beta \in (-1,1)$ as

$$ f(\alpha, \beta) = \int_0^{\infty} dx \: \frac{x^{\alpha}}{1+2 x \cos{(\pi \beta)} + x^2}$$

One can use, for example, the Residue Theorem to show that

$$ f(\alpha, \beta) = \frac{\pi \sin{\left (\pi \alpha \beta\right )}}{ \sin{\left (\pi \alpha\right )} \,  \sin{\left (\pi \beta\right )}} $$

Clearly, from this latter expression, $f(\alpha, \beta) = f(\beta, \alpha)$.  My question is, can one see this symmetry directly from the integral expression?

Comment: the final answer on MSE, which rewrites the integral identically as $f(\alpha,\beta)=-(\sin\pi\alpha\beta)(\sin\pi\beta)^{-1}\int_0^\infty dx\,x^\alpha/(1+x)$ goes a long way towards demonstrating the symmetry (because the remaining integral evaluates to $-\pi/\sin\pi\alpha$); but you probably want to avoid any evaluation at all, right?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: that is correct - we should be able to see why the evaluation leads to a symmetric function without any evaluation of the integral.  Or so I hope.

Comment: It seems tempting to write the integrand in terms of a Poisson kernel: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_unit_disc

Comment: have a look at this [posting](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/890328/87355) --- there is some integration involved, but only elementary integrals, no contour integration --- does it qualify as an answer?